# Does anyone know any train timetable API service?

Tags: php, javascript, python, api

### UPDATE

time is passing, but something is moving (europe): a friend of mine showed me this: http://project.irail.be/  Atm it works just for Belgium.

im wondering if there is any online service who provide API about the train timetables (arrivals, departure, etch..), at least for the european stations.

I know www.bahn.de, who provide the accurated timetables for many european countries, but i didin't find any similar to a api service.

My goal (well, just a *future-project*) is to develope an application like gmaps, but instead of giving the car-trip i would like to give the train-trip.. you know, the user set the departure day, time and station, then the first arrival, maybe then add another one, and so on.

So, there is something like, that can be queryed by php/python/javascript?

**Edit:** if can help, im wondering to build a service to plan an inter-rail trip! (and any help will be really appreciate)

Im stuck.
Google's public-service api rely on the information that every local company makes avaiable, much branches are missing (for example, is almost impossible to use it to build an itinerary that touches two or more regions of Europe.
As i said before, the only service that i know doing it good is the bahn.de, they really have all the data.. but no api.
I tryed to parse theyre result page (in order to use them as API), but seem like the markup is been build exactly to avoid that.. maybe they have business plans behind that or whatever, but i dont think they will ever release some API.. so, my project is going on without this function (p.s: my project is about non-profit cultural organizations, we wont make war to anyone ;P)

@El Goorf: if you find a way, and consider the idea of sharing it, count on my hand if need help!

Comment: wouldn't you duplicate the functionality of bahn.de? they have the exact route planner you describe.

Comment: Yes.. well, i dont want to reinvent the wheel, but what i'm trying to figure out is an web application chained to gmaps, panoramio and wikimage, where people would be able to build-edit-then share with friends they'rs trip's... i cant redirect to bahn.de for paln the trip, then get back for the locations, suggested places, etc.. ;)

Answer (score 8):

FYI. National Rail in the UK don't provide an API for their UK train data and get very funny about developers calling forms/scraping pages from third party apps. It's a very strange closed model. Google or the BBC might be your best bet, although the BBC provide travel information as opposed to time tables.

Comment: Frankly the UK train system in it's entirety is a very strange closed model, and that's the family friendly version.

Comment: They do provide a web service: http://realtime.nationalrail.co.uk/ldbws/ However, they have recently made it so you need to buy an API toke - it was previously free. This could be the result of somebody offering the rail times for free, undercutting their own iphone/android apps.

Comment: ATOC have now made timetable data available - http://www.atoc.org/about-atoc/rail-settlement-plan/data-feeds/conditions

Answer (score 4):

Not exactly what you're looking for, but have you looked at http://www.livedepartureboards.co.uk/ldbws/? It is an API for the UK railways... but for arrivals and departures only, not planning more than a couple of hours in advance!

Still, it's a start!

Answer (score 1):

Something in a common format like [Google Transit Feed](http://code.google.com/transit/spec/transit_feed_specification.html)?, there are some [US based](http://code.google.com/p/googletransitdatafeed/wiki/PublicFeeds) ones, as well as one I found for [London](http://www.tfl.gov.uk/businessandpartners/syndication/default.aspx).

Comment: Yes, something like GTF but worldwide -or at least- to the europe...
Well, seem like google is 'waiting' that the public agency give he the data, so should be just  a matter of time.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, as far as I know there is no publicly-available timetable data in Europe so far.  As garrow pointed out above, many agencies in the U.S., Australia, and Canada have taken the lead in making this information available to developers, but other parts of the world haven't yet followed suit.  I recommend following the [Transit Developers group](http://groups.google.com/group/transit-developers) and the [OpenStreetMap talk-transit list](http://lists.openstreetmap.org/listinfo/talk-transit), as those are the places where developers are most likely to discuss new data releases.

Comment: For the europe, the website bahn.de seem to have the traintable for the 90% of europe (in my case, italy, the bahn.de timetables are more accurate then the trenitalia.it timetables -.-)...
So there must be something outta here even for europe.. i've tryed to contact bahn.de, but no answer..

Answer (score 1):

The UK train timetable data is available from:

http://data.atoc.org/how-to

It's available free, including for commercial use. It's not an API, but a 40M zip file containing the data in an archaic fixed field format.  There seems to be an opensource project that can parse this data, [librailfare on sourceforge](http://librailfare.sourceforge.net/) (thanks to [lefterav](https://stackoverflow.com/users/865586/lefterav) for pointing this out).

The spec for the data is here:

http://travelinedata.org.uk/CIF/atco-cif-spec.pdf

and here:

http://data.atoc.org/sites/all/themes/atoc/files/rsps5041%20-%20Timetable%20Data.pdf

Comment: I was looking for something _real time_
At the moment, this feature has been delayed in my project.. but i'll keep an eye open about ;)

Comment: Yeah, there's no realtime data available for free (yet) :-(

Answer (score 1):

For trains in **Sweden**, there's http://www.trafiklab.se where APIs are available for basically all public transport in Sweden, most of it (including trains) with real time information about disturbances. Only in Swedish though.

Answer (score 1):

The French National Railway Company just released an API to access its train timetable data: 
https://data.sncf.com

Answer (score 0):

Did anyone manage to come up with anything for this?  I've also been on the lookout for a European train timetable API.  The best I've been able to come up with is this free data source: http://www.bahn.de/p/view/buchung/karten/dbfahrplanbest.shtml

It's an app which installs locally.. now if there was a way to get the data out of it and load it into a db that'd be great!

Comment: Yep I already saw that page, but i dont think it can solve the problem. First of all: does them allow you to use theyre data in the way you'll gonna use them? Second: you have to build your own data structure and route querys - Third: what about updates? My best bet was to use an some kind of api - i tryed to contact them few times without answer

Comment: Yeah.. I had intended on building my own route queries but the other two issues are quite valid.  Even if the data could be pulled from the app (I had a brief look at writing an auto content grabber specifically for the app, but gave up on the idea), it would be difficult to process it into some sort of data structure, especially for my needs.

Comment: I've tryed to scrap the bahn.de booking form results, but the DOM looks like its been build just for making scraping hard ;)

Comment: You are not allowed to use the timetable from bahn.de for commercial purposes